# How to change the UI theme according to the device(windows, iphone, android, etc) in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs

How to change the "UI theme" according to the device(windows, iphone, android, etc) in "Sencha touch"

Answer (score 0):

- Open a command prompt, change the directory where Sencha Touch installed
- Run the following command
  `sencha generate app {app name} {app path}`

This command will generate skeleton of the your application. After that, you will see a file name `app.json` in the root of the directory.

Open this file an editor. You will see a property named `css`. This is the property that you should work with. For instance;

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "resources/css/ie10.css",
        "platform": ["ie10"]
    },
    {
        "path": "resources/css/ios.css",
        "platform": ["ios"]
    }
]
```

Checkout this video:
[Theme Switching in Sencha Touch](http://vimeo.com/66191847)